# Which of the following is correct? "as I/me/mine"

Tags: comparative-constructions

> She has the same religious beliefs as I. (I do)
>
> She has the same religious beliefs as me. (sounds wrong)
>
> She has the same religious beliefs as mine. (just how you say "she has the same car as mine?")

Answer (score 1):

*As I* is correct and formal. *As me* is correct and informal. *As I* could be regarded as ellipsis of *as I do*, as you say. In fact, the *as [pronoun] [verb]* construction is more preferred than the *as [pronoun]* one.

> She has the same religious beliefs **as I do**.

To make the *as mine* example sound natural, you could rewrite it as

> Her religious beliefs are the same as mine.

Take a look at [this post](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/311981/353947) on ELU. Since *mine* is possessive, it sounds better when it's related to another possessive construction.

---

From *Practical English Usage*, Unit 174:

> After *as* and *than*, object forms are generally used in an informal style.
>   *My sister’s nearly as tall **as me**. I can run faster **than her**.*
>
> In a more formal style, subject forms are used, usually followed by verbs.
>   *My sister’s nearly as tall **as I am**. I can run faster **than she can**.*

*PEU* doesn't recommend using the *as [pronoun]* construction without a verb (Unit 203).

> A subject form without a verb (e.g. *as well as he*) is unusual in this structure in modern English.

*A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language* gives the same advice (Unit 6.4):

> *He* is { more intelligent than | as intelligent as } *she* (is). [2]
>
> But in response forms and comparative constructions, the subjective pronoun on its own, such as *she* in [2], sometimes gives a stilted impression, and it is preferable to add the operator after it: *she is*.

From *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, Chapter 5, 16.2.1:

```
i   a. She is older than he.              b. She is older than him.  
ii  a. She went to the same school as I.  b. She went to the same school as me.  
iii a. I’ve not met a nicer man than he.  b. I’ve not met a nicer man than him.
```

> If the complement of *than* or *as* can be expanded by the addition of a verb to which the pronoun is subject, then formal style has a nominative, informal style an accusative. In [i–iii], for example, we can expand the [a] versions to *older than he is*, *the same school as I went to*, *a nicer man than he is*. ... Some speakers may find the nominative less likely in [iii] than in [i–ii]: in [i–ii] the pronoun is matched against the subject of the matrix clause, but this is not so in [iii].

You might also be interested in [this article](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/than-what-follows-it-and-why) on *than I* and *than me*.

Answer (score 0):

Below different examples from literature. Different cases of using **I, me, mine**:
(without links because too many examples):

**same ... as I.**

> “I find more comfort with ones who walked the same path as I.
>   That one, I think, hides behind much the same mask as I.

My attention in saying from "I".

**same ... as me.**
*This is mistake, but commonly used in informal speech.*

> He looks the same age as me, he could be my father. 
>   They looked to be the same age as me, or perhaps a little older — it was difficult to tell from so far away. 
>   He pushed off the desk and took one step forward, which put him in the same breathing space as me…if he actually needed to breathe. 
>   “She can scarcely stand to be in the same country as me, let alone the same bed. 
>   ‘He was exactly the same height as me — six foot.’
>   He had the same name and rank as me, this old man?”
>   ‘Same height as me but slim, fair, blue eyes. .’

Saying about somebody else.

**same ... as mine.**

> It was even, as far as I could tell in the dark, the same make as mine. 
>   Her eyes were at the same level as mine.
>   At least, his reason goes the same way as mine. 
>   Her cheeks, her chin, her mouth, all were precisely the same shape as mine. 
>   You’ll run out of arrows eventually and I doubt your men have the same stomach for a fight as mine. 
>   Your blood is rooted in the same place as mine. 
>   Dad's investigation seemed to have been  following the same frustrating dead-end paths as  mine.
>   “I booked you on the same flight as mine.”

Affiliation is emphasized.

I hope these examples will help you feel the difference.

Comment: "The same as me" is technically incorrect, though it is commonly used in casual speech. The reason is what you have shown in your first example: "She has the same X as I" implies "...as I do (or have)".

Comment: Thank you! "The same as me" - not mistake, but like a easy style of speech? I think if this's strict mistake I couldn't  found so many examples with this case in literature. Because if I need to understand real English, I think that important thing to know difference between strict unusable mistake and easy speech style.

Comment: It is incorrect according to the strict rules of grammar, though, as I said, it is commonly used in colloquial (informal) speech.

Comment: Thank you again, Kate Bunting! I've added this thing into my answer. This is really interesting language phenomena when rules which firstly came from language practice, now have conflict with real today language practice.

Comment: @sayfriend It'd be more of a mistake to say *same as I*. It's what people sometimes *produce* (i.e. unnaturally) after they have been taught their own instincts about their mother tongue are wrong, i.e. what user Kate Bunting said above. It's not careless or wrong or overly colloquial to say *same as me*. It would be completely neutral, however, to say *same as I do* (in the example in the question) and overly formal to say *same as I*, or perhaps a some kind of hypercorrection in informal / neutral speech.

Comment: I wholeheartedly support your examples approach (where you provide examples of similar or the same constructions), but it is flawed; in particular in discussing register / style, and the way you compare the results (if you show 3 examples of all the options the asker provided, does that mean they're all equally likely to occur?). For that I'd like to point you to curated corpora such as BNC and COCA (you can make a free account), and particularly the latter due to its size, where you can, to a degree, control the mentioned variables.

Comment: Thank you, this is totally right! I hope that my skill will be bigger than now and I'll can better understand difference between different classes of examples (this is too difficult to me for now). In the future I want to give "No warranty" notice about examples in my answers. And I want to give examples just as a base for thinking. I will get to know more about BNC and COCA, maybe it is what I need to learn more. Thank you again!